# Remove duplicates from field [array]

Tags: views, search

I am using php in views and trying to make a custom field to remove the duplicates in [field_trucks_notification_no_ref_node_eb:field_trucks_agency] field, i tried to use the row->field_name from the available variables in Global:PHP (output) with no luck.

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [entity] => 268
        [_entity_properties] => Array
            (
                [search_api_relevance] => 1
                [search_api_excerpt] => 
                [search_api_id] => 268
                [field_cons_country_border] => 35604
                [field_trucks_notification_no_ref_node_eb] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 269
                        [1] => 272
                        [2] => 278
                    )

                [field_trucks_notification_no_ref_node_eb:field_trucks_agency] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 35617
                        [1] => 35621
                        [2] => 35617
                    )
```

EDIT: using Global:PHP field in views, How can I retrieve the values of the last field (array) above and remove duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates in Views, if the views advanced settings "Distinct" don't operate, have a look at Views Distinct module: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct. Really useful project and sounds better than php in views.

Comment: Sorry for bad answer formatting, I'm writing from phone ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using it with no luck that's why I'm looking to make it in php. Because the field values (taxonomy terms) are already aggregated together via Search API and entity backreference

Comment: So consider editing your question and be more precise with the context, and what you tried so far to solve your issue. ;)

Comment: question edited :)